# CloverETL : How to connect to a server using ssh key

Tags: ssh-keys, cloveretl

I have a clover job that used to connect  and transfer files from sftp using File URL = sftp://${SFTP_USERNAME}:${SFTP_PASSWORD}@${SFTP_SERVER}/${SFTP_SOURCE_PATH}${SOURCE_FILE_MASK}, but now I need to change the approach and connect to the location using a ssh key. How the parameters should be passed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put ssh key into specific folder 'ssh-keys' into your project (key need to have '.key' suffix and be in OpenSSH format). Then you will omit password parameter (eg. :${SFTP_PASSWORD} portion).
You can have multiple keys in the same folder, Clover loops through all of them and tries to connect.

Here is a link to forum where they are solving it https://forum.cloverdx.com/viewtopic.php?t=6799

Comment: Would appreciate accepting answer if it is appropriate.